# Reduce Myrange from paragraph into two lines

Tags: vba, ms-word, range, paragraph

After setting `Myrange` of the first paragraph. I need to evaluate number of lines of current paragraph, if lines are less then 3 then following code will turn font into **bold**.

```
Set Myrange= Selection.Range.PARAGRAPHS(1).Range

If Myrange.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticLines) < 3 Then
Myrange.Font.Bold = True

Else

Set Twolines = myrange.Duplicate
'''Here I want to reduce Myrange to only 2 lines
End If
```

so my question is how can I change `Myrange` from paragraph into 2 lines?

I had been doing this by `Selection method` and don't know how to perform it using `Ranges`. e.g.

```
Selection.ExtendMode = True
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2
```

Comment: The wdLine constant is only recognised by the Selection.Range method.  If you want to find the end of the second line using a Word.range then you will have to use a loop and reduce the twolines range word by word until your compute statistics say that there are two lines.  Lookup at the .MoveEnd method for range objects.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have, using the `Selection` object, is really the only way.

"Lines" and "pages" in a Word document have no corresponding objects in the Word object model. Unlike `Words` or `Paragraphs`, for example, lines and pages are "dynamic": where a line or page break occurs depends totally on how Word's layout engine, in concert with the current print driver, processes the document in a particular session. It's quite possible that a line or page break is different on one computer than on another. And they will certainly change "fluidly" as a document is being edited.

For this reason, it's not really possible to deal with a line or a page as an "object" in the progamming sense of the term. That's why it's only possible to deal with these by using `Selection`.